# How do I insert values from first and second API response into my 3rd API call's request ? (Angular RXJS)

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

```
        registerUser(){
    
          let payload={
            "Id": 0,
            "UserId": 0,
            "AccountName": this.formData?.companyName,
            "Address": this.formData?.address,
            "Email": this.formData?.email,
            "MobileNumber": this.formData?.contactNumber,
            "UserName": this.formData?.userId,
            "Password": this.formData?.password,
          }
          this.registerService.registerUserFormData(payload) //for registering account details
        .pipe(tap((resp:any)=>{
          this.accountData=resp.data //storing the response into a variable for later use
        }),
        switchMap((response1:any)=>{ 
     
          const formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('file', this.registerService.companyRegistrationDocument);
      
    
        return this.registerService.uploadFile(formData)
          
    }),
    switchMap( (response2:any) =>{
      let payload=[
        {
          "Id":0,
          "AccountId": this.accountData.id,
          "Name": response2.data.name
        }]
        console.log(payload) //all values are defined here
        return this.registerService.uploadDocumentData(payload) //but when sending the api request "accountId" becomes undefined here
        } 
        ),).subscribe({next:(responseMain)=>{
          console.log(responseMain)
          alert("Your account details have been registered successfully")
           },
          error:()=>{
            alert("An error occurred, please try again")
          }})
          }
```

Given the above code, my requirement here is to send an initial API call to save data of a newly created account, followed by a document upload in the second API call, and then in the third API call I will send a payload comprising of some data from first and second API call's response data objects.

The issue I face here is that the first API call's response data comes as undefined when I try to declare it into the payload of third API call (when I console the payload, the data is defined, but on sending the API call, the request body property of that value comes up undefined, while the second API call data shows up fine in all cases). Is there any workaround for this issue? or am I missing something

(In the future, I may also have to incorporate multiple file uploads in the future, so it maybe necessary to reuse the response data from first API call in the subsequent API calls' request body)

Comment: You could use the `localStorage` browser api.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [forkJoin](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/forkjoin) operator for this.
It combines the results of multiple observable into one new observable.

```
registerUser() {
  let payload={
    "Id": 0,
    "UserId": 0,
    "AccountName": this.formData?.companyName,
    "Address": this.formData?.address,
    "Email": this.formData?.email,
    "MobileNumber": this.formData?.contactNumber,
    "UserName": this.formData?.userId,
    "Password": this.formData?.password,
  }
  forkJoin({
    register: this.registerService.registerUserFormData(payload),
    fileUpload: this.uploadFile$())
  }).pipe(
    switchMap((response) => { //You can use response.register and response.fileUpload, to get the responses form both observables in the switchmap
      let payload=[
      {
        "Id": 0,
        "AccountId": response.register.id,
        "Name": response.fileUpload.name
      }]

      return this.registerService.uploadDocumentData(payload)
    })
  ).subscribe({
      next: (responseMain) => {
        console.log(responseMain)
        alert("Your account details have been registered successfully")
      },
      error: () => {
        alert("An error occurred, please try again")
      }
    });
}

//To make it less cluttered I moved the observable into it's own method
uploadFile$() {
  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('file', this.registerService.companyRegistrationDocument);
    
  return this.registerService.uploadFile(formData)  
}
```